# Color specific words (keywords) in a text that is inside a <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I'm working im a project and now I need do something that I don't know. I want to color specfic words (keywords) in a text that is inside a `<td>`

I can do it static, because the texts are random, they come from database.

Its a normal text, I want to color words like "animal, pet", something like this.
And put a specific color for each one, for exemple, animal appers like red, and pet like blue font color.

I think I have to use Jquery do to it, and make a function to do it after the page loads (readyFunction).

But I dont have any ideas to do it, I'm new with jquery. Could you give me some ideas, please ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really "dirty" solution, but will serve you as an example on how to approach your task:

```
<body>
  <table id="the_table">
   <tr>
     <td>random words from DB: like an apple, pet, whatever, yet another apple</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var content_cell,
    random_words = "",
    colors_map = {
      "apple": "red",
      "pet": "blue"
    };
   // selector for your specific table cell
    $('#the_table tr').each(function() {
      content_cell = $(this).find("td:first");    
    });
    // get cell content
    random_words = content_cell.html();
    // replace your keywords according the map
    $.each(colors_map, function( index, value ) {
      random_words = random_words.replace(new RegExp(index, 'g'), "<font color='" + value + "'>" + index + "</font>");
    });
    // set back html content into the cell
    content_cell.html(random_words);
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sulution, i'm gonna use it as example. Can you explain me this line ? "$.each(colors_map, function( index, value ) {
      random_words = random_words.replace(new RegExp(index, 'g'), "<font color='" + value + "'>" + index + "</font>");
    });
" -- I didin't understand, what i'm replacing ? For what i see i'm doing a loop in colorsMap but it's all what i got...

Comment: Inside $each handler function you will get key and value of each element of the color to keyword map. Each time you would try to find the "index" in the text with RegEx globally (all entries). If found, you replace each of them with the same "index", but wrapped with <font> tag, where the color set to "value" of your map. If nothing found, iterator $each would go to next map entry and so on. Let me know if something else is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for explaining better, I believe I will need to change a little. But i'ts amazing, very good solution. Do you really think that is "dirty", so i can make it better ?

Comment: You should write your own selector, as I used find("td:first"), which may be not your case; you should do the checks the selector return some html content at all; you should probably take a look on case sensitivity and so on ... lots of work to make it reliable piece of code ;)

Comment: You're right, thanks for all your help, man. Now i'll try to make a solution based on yours, like color all words that are between "{}" for example. Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your browser support html5, No JQuery is need, try the following code:

```
function renderKey(){
  //create color list in case you don't want to get invisible color such as 'white' from random color..
  // make the list long enough to avoid duplicated color 
  var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'cyan', 'black']; 
  var keyColor = {};
  var keyIndex = 0;

  //you may need more selectors to exclude unexpected elements, e.g. <td> in <thead>.
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("td");    
  for (i in x){ 
    //suppose your key words seperated by ',' in <td>
    var keyWords = x[i].innerHTML.split(',');    
    x[i].innerHTML =  keyWords.reduce(
      function(total, value, index){
        return total + '<span style="color:' + 
             (keyColor[value] || (keyColor[value] = colors[ keyIndex++ % colors.length])) + 
             '">' + value + '</span>';
      },
      ''
    );      
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sulution, i'm gonna use it as example. Because i need to color the words with specific color, for exemple, word "pet" always have color blue. And don't color the words thar aren't my KeyWords. But it gonna help me aloot !